# ERROR: The value expression referenced by column xxx can not directly contain a summary function in Proc SQL set statement

Tags: function, set, proc-sql

What I want is to add a column to my existing table to compare the individual country `new_cases` with the `global_average_new_cases` for COVID evolution based on country and date.

And I want the result to be a binary value, which means that, if the individual country new cases of a specific date is greater than the global average new cases on the same date, then it will return 1, else it will return 0.

I can only use Proc SQL to write the code to achieve such result.

I have tried the following:

```
proc sql;

alter table devoirb.covid_data

add compare_global_average num(7);

update devoirb.covid_data

set 

compare_global_average =

case when nouveaux_cas > avg(nouveaux_cas) then 1 else 0
end;

quit;
```

And, when I run this code, it returns with the following error message:

**ERROR: The value expression referenced by column compare_global_average can not directly contain a summary function.**

Based on my understanding, this error message means that I cannot use the `avg` function in my set statement when I want to assign values to my `compare_global_average` column.

Could anyone help me on solving this issue? Is there any other way of writing such code to attempt what I expect in Proc SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery in this case:

```
update devoirb.covid_data
    set compare_global_average = (case when nouveaux_cas > (select avg(nouveaux_cas) from devoirb.covid_data)
                                       then 1 else 0
                                   end);
quit;
```

Comment: I have tried your code but it returns me with another error, please see in the below commentsWARNING: A value expression of the SET clause references the data set being updated.
ERROR: You cannot reopen DEVOIRB.COVID_DATA.DATA for update access with member-level control because DEVOIRB.COVID_DATA.DATA is in 
use by you in resource environment SQL (2).
ERROR: PROC SQL could not undo this statement if an ERROR were to happen as it could not obtain exclusive access to the data set. 
       This statement will not execute as the SQL option UNDO_POLICY=REQUIRED is in effect.

Comment: @Heng . . . I didn't realize SAS had this limitation.  That means that you may need to store the results in a temporary table.

Comment: Thank you for your help, do you mean that I will create a temporary table and then join the two table together afterwards ?

Comment: @Heng . . . Yes.  The temporary table would only have the average.  You could also create a view to calculate the value on the fly.

Comment: I will do this instead. Thank you so much for your help !